# Running two functions independent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Testing on the following demo I saw an issue:

DEMO: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JHVH5/1/)

When you drag the bar on the first image, does on the second image also (not the main problem, but could be great if somehow are independent of each other).

But the main trouble is on the second image, since dragging the bar, does not upload the before/after image at the moment (as the first example does). It first moves the bar, and when the button is released, it adjusts the image.

Example image (error on red):
[image: example]

How could I make it upload at the same moment than moving the bar?

In the other hand, could be possible doing both independent without creating a whole new script (I found this one solution, but for obviously reasons is not the best result).

The following code creates the bar:

```
var $dragMe  = $(".dragme");
```

Comment: Can you force updates on mousedown event on the bar?

Comment: you could change code to use http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events ? the "drag" event is what your looking for here, it fires as dragging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `jQuery.each` for create independent instances =]

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JHVH5/2/

Comment: I tried to use `.each()`, but my code was a little messier than yours: http://jsfiddle.net/V3FJ8/